# Trying to find text on webpage that has no id using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, parsing

I'm trying to find text on a webpage that's not marked with a specific ID or tag. It's just plain text produced by an external actor that I have no control over.

Anyway to locate this?

I should probably mention that I'm doing automated testing using WatiN, and want to click a button next to a certain text ("Ny Linje").
I could of course just hardcode the button-id, but I imagine the test will fail eventually if this is done.

The graphical output of this is something like below, but with several rows (Where || represents a cell in a table):

|| [BUTTON] || Ny Linje || Some other content...

Comment: I would think that going with the clicking the button ID approach would be best? Especially if you can be guarenteed a static ID on the button by whoever is developing this.

Comment: Are you open to using a library like http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is a rather large system, so there's no guarantees that this will keep static. I'm working for an ISP, and the case in question is supposed to check for whatever first available, free connection to an address. Bad formulation? -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually ended up doing like this:

```
_ctsLineListSearchGrid.Find(By.Tag("input",15)).Click();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Watin and if you know the text value of the button you can find an element by it's value (as opposed to the id).  For example:

```
    private Button DownloadButton
    {
        get
        {
            return Document.Button(Find.ByValue("Download"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the button ID would be more static than the content on a page, I would suggest using the button id and changing if it were to ever begin failing because that button was moved.